# Why does Indy pause while writing "neolithic" in the campus scene?

Tags: indiana-jones, raiders-of-the-lost-ark

In the university campus scene in *Raiders of the Lost Ark*, Indy is writing "NEOLITHIC" on a blackboard. He reaches 'H', but pauses after putting down the two vertical strokes, seemingly confirms something and resumes writing it. What is the meaning of this?

[image: animated GIF of scene described above]

Comment: Do you mean when he checks that he spelled the word correctly? Isn't it just him in his awkward, hesitant professor persona?

Comment: One of the most famous monoliths is Stonehenge, which is several stones standing straight up.  Note how many times he draws a straight line standing on end in a row.

Answer (score 15):

**He's reminding himself how to spell the word.**

If you listen, he spells the word to himself, trying to remember the correct letters.

> "Neo," meaning "new"
>   and "lithic"... L-I-T-H...I-C, meaning "stone."

That's all it is.  A minor gag, just the slightly absent-minded professor of archaeology needing to remember how to spell an archaeological word.